# password in login program ( Python)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i have wrote simple script for login.
I don't understand what's wrong with the code:
1.) i have used getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter password: ")), but it displays the password at run time and also it shows the warning. How to ignore that.

2.) How to use try-except to catch wrong logins.

```
class login:
    print "Login Page" 
    def __init__(self,id,pas):
        self.id="admin"
        self.pas="admin"

    def check(self,id,pas):
        if(self.id==log.id and self.pas==log.pas):
            print "Login success!"
        else:
            print "who r u???"


log=login("","")
import getpass
log.check(raw_input("Enter Login ID:"),getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter password: "))
```

Output:

```
    Login Page
Enter Login ID:ad

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\getpass.py", line 92
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Enter password: ad
who r u???
```

Comment: Are you running in linux or windows?

It runs fine in  my Linux, but there is a bug in your check function.

I think your condition in the if statement should be

if (self.id==id and self.pas==pas):

Comment: what do you mean by "How to use try-except to catch wrong logins.?". It seems you are already checking it with if-else.

Comment: @mrcl i am running it in windows

Comment: Any luck on finding answer yet? or have you tried using anything else than IDLE?

Comment: @Lafexlos yes i found the answer. All i need to do was to replace self.id and self.pass with id and pass resp.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows worked fine, try this:

```
class login:
    print "Login Page"

    def __init__(self, id, pas):
        self.id = "admin"
        self.pas = "admin"

    def check(self, id, pas):

        if(self.id == id and self.pas == pas):
            print ("Login success!")
        else:
            print ("who r u???")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = login("", "")
    id1 = raw_input("Enter Login ID: ")
    pas1 = raw_input("Enter password: ")
    log.check(id1, pas1)
```